# Can add action with addTarget to uibutton but it doesn't do anything

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, segue, presentviewcontroller

i have a relatively small project with two View Controllers. On every View Controller I added some buttons and labels programmatically.

The button on the first View Controller works as expected.

First Controller: GoalsVC

```
class GoalsVC: UIViewController {

let topView: UIView = { ... }()

let topViewTitleLabel: UILabel = { ... }()

let topViewAddButton: UIButton = {
    ...
    // Add actions
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addGoalPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

let goalsTableView: UITableView = { ... }()

let firstGoalLabel: UILabel = { ... }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    setupLayoutTopView()
    ...
}

func setupLayoutTopView() {

    view.addSubview(topView)
   ...

    topView.addSubview(topViewTitleLabel)
    ...

    topView.addSubview(topViewAddButton)
    ...
}

func setupTableView() {

    ...

}

// Actions

@objc private func addGoalPressed() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: CREATE_GOAL_SEGUE, sender: nil)
} }
```

After pressing the button, the action worked as expected and did a segue to the next view controller, but on the next view controller I added actions to the button and didn't fired up the action. There is no reaction at all.

Second View Controller:

```
class CreateGoalVC: UIViewController {

let topView: UIView = { ... }()

let topViewTitleLabel: UILabel = { ... }()

let topViewUnwindButton: UIButton = {

...
    // Add actions
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(unwindPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLayoutTopView()
}

func setupLayoutTopView() {

    self.view.addSubview(topView)
    ...
    topView.addSubview(topViewTitleLabel)
    ...
    topView.addSubview(topViewUnwindButton)
    ...
}

// Actions

@objc func unwindPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What I also tested:
If i do an instance of the new View Controller and present it instead of doing a segue, the button works as expected.

```
@objc private func addGoalPressed() {
    let vc = CreateGoalVC()
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

In short:

- Addtarget to button works on the first View Controller and everytime I call present to switch to the next View Controller
- The button action doesn't work when using a segue to switch to the next view controller.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Did you set the class of the second VC in the storyboard in the identity inspector?

Comment: Does that segue (CREATE_GOAL_SEGUE) do `present` or `push`? If it's `push` then the `dismiss` function might not work. Also, have you tried `print` in `unwindPressed(_ sender:)` function, just want to know if it's called at all.

Comment: Yes i did set the vc in the storyboard inspector and CREATE_GOAL_SEGUE is a let constant with the identifier. The segue works as expected.

Comment: I already tried a print and also set a breakpoint there, but nothing happens. It never enters the event function. The segue does a push